# Rails 4 nested resource hash not committed to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first app in Rails 4, but I'm not sure whether Rails 4 is the problem.

I have nested resources as follows:

```
resources :made_games do
  resources :made_game_instances
end
```

When I try to save a new `made_game_instance` this is what's happening in the log:

```
Started POST "/made_games/11/made_game_instances" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-10 12:03:55      -0700
Processing by MadeGameInstancesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jEN2syjftjRtf3DBnijtp7gNVUEFrI+HYTUs+HFgo5M=", "made_game_instance"=>{"new_word1"=>"bluesky"}, "commit"=>"Create Made game instance", "made_game_id"=>"11"}
MadeGame Load (122.7ms)  SELECT "made_games".* FROM "made_games" WHERE "made_games"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "11"]]
(14.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (215.9ms)  INSERT INTO "made_game_instances" ("created_at", "made_game_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:03:55 UTC +00:00], ["made_game_id", 11], ["updated_at", Tue, 10 Sep 2013 19:03:55 UTC +00:00]]
(5.7ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/made_games/11/made_game_instances/5
Completed 302 Found in 458ms (ActiveRecord: 358.3ms)
```

You can see that the params hash contains the hash where the `new_game_instance` attribute `:new_word1` is assigned the value "bluesky." What I cannot figure out is why this assignment does not appear in the SQL that is subsequently generated when the new 'made_game_instances' object is created.

**Additional information**

Since this is Rails 4, in order to whitelist all the parameters (at least at this stage in development), I have used permit! in the params private method at the bottom of the controllers for both `made_games` and `made_game_instances`.

The `made_games` controller:

```
class MadeGamesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @made_game = MadeGame.new
  end

  def create
    @made_game = MadeGame.new(made_game_params)
    if @made_game.save
      flash[:notice] = "Here you go!"
      redirect_to @made_game
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something about that didn't work, unfortunately."
      render :action => new
    end
  end

  def show
    @made_game = MadeGame.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def made_game_params
      params.require(:made_game).permit!
    end
end
```

Here is a link to the github repo: https://github.com/keb97/madlibs/tree/users_making

The form used to create a new `made_game_instance` is:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@made_game, @made_game_instance] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.input :new_word1, label: @made_game.word1.to_s %>
  </p>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I should also note that there is one form for made_game, and a separate form for made_game_instance, rather than a nested form, so I do not believe this is an issue of accepts_nested_attributes_for or fields_for.

Comment: The `params` says `new_word1` and not `new_word`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's a typo in my post. I just confirmed in the schema that the column in the table is indeed called `new_word1`. I will edit the OP accordingly.

Comment: Could you post your made_games controller please?

Comment: I added the made_games controller at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Can you post your form code? Or a link to a github repo?

Comment: I'm new too, but isn't there something about has_many relations need something like `.build` instead of `.new`... Also does your model have `accepts_nested_atrtributes_for`? See this [page](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/52960938209/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)

Comment: @Beartech here is a github repo for this: https://github.com/keb97/madlibs/tree/users_making the form is at app/views/made_game_instances/new.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your made_games_instance_controller.rb

this line...

```
@made_game_instance = @made_game.made_game_instances.build(params[:made_game_instance_params])
```

should actually be...

```
@made_game_instance = @made_game.made_game_instances.build(made_game_instance_params)
```

There is no params hash entry with a symbol key :made_game_instance_params

Comment: Thank you, this was precisely the problem!